# Draw curved lines using tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

How can I draw curved lines outside the main diagram?

[image]

I've already drawn the diagram (white), but I need to add the red curved lines, how can I do it?
My (amazing) code is, compiled with `LuaLaTeX`, and using atom with the LaTex package I get this diagram, which is different from the diagram generated on overleaf using the same code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a);
            \vertex (b);
            \vertex (c);
            \vertex (d);
            \vertex (e);
            \diagram[thick, horizontal= a to e]{
                a -- [fermion]b[dot],
                c--[anti fermion]b,
                d--[anti fermion]b,
                e--[fermion]b,
            };
            \vertex[below=1em of a]{$a$};
            \vertex[below=1em of b]{$b$};
            \vertex[below=1em of c]{$c$};
            \vertex[below=1em of d]{$d$};
            \vertex[below=1em of e]{$e$};

        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this it is my output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You also need to keep your code minimal to a certain extend. Surely externalisation and beautiful colors are not relevant for your problem!? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Remove duplicate packages from preamble and check if your code compiles.

Comment: @john: with this preamble (removing duplicate packages), your code work `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
` However, it gives a picture that is much different with the picture you posted.

Comment: @BlackMild Excuse me. I have read now your message. I was improving the code of the user.

Comment: @BlackMild I don't know why, but using atom instead of overleaf I get a different diagram, anyway I've uploaded the diagram I get for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\pagecolor{black}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45, white]
        \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a);
            \vertex (b);
            \vertex (c);
            \vertex (d);
            \vertex (e);
            \diagram[thick, horizontal= a to e]{
                a -- [fermion]b[dot],
                c--[anti fermion]b,
                d--[anti fermion]b,
                e--[fermion]b,
            };
            \vertex[below=1em of a]{$a$};
            \vertex[below=1em of b]{$b$};
            \vertex[below=1em of c]{$c$};
            \vertex[below=1em of d]{$d$};
            \vertex[below=1em of e]{$e$};
            \draw[->, thick, red, shorten <=0.4 cm, shorten >=0.4 cm] ($ (a)!0.1!(c) $) to[out=0, in=270] ($ (a)!0.9!(c) $) ;     
            \draw[->, thick, red, shorten <=0.4 cm, shorten >=0.4 cm] ($ (d)!0.1!(e) $) to[out=90, in=180] ($ (d)!0.9!(e) $) ;     
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Feynman diagram with two curved arrows]

Comment: This looks like what I need. Later I'll try and let you know. The command "draw" is from tikz right? So I can look at documentation

Comment: Yes `feynman` is within TikZ, so everything works the same. You can also use the solution from @Black Mild, you just need to shift the `\draw` to the correct position e.i. centered at `(b)`.

Comment: I tried to compile, with LuaLatex using atom, but I get this (removed the color) https://imgur.com/a/OOfTKpK . I'm start thinking the problem is with my editor and the compiler, since I had problems also with vertex positioning. I'll try it on overleaf too

Comment: Apparently the problem was with my setup: I installed only "LaTex core", which probably didn't contained all the necessary packages. Anyway now it work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\pagecolor{black}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,thick,rotate=-45,cap=rect]
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}{
\begin{scope}[rotate=90*\i,white]
\draw[->] (0,0)--(2,0);
\draw (2,0)--(3.5,0);   
\end{scope}
}

\begin{scope}[red,smooth]
\draw[<-] plot[domain=1/3:3] (\x,1/\x);     
\draw[->] plot[domain=-1/3:-3] (\x,1/\x);   
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks nice, but I need to do it using the "tikz-feynman"  package. Also, colors are just here to make clear what I've already drawn and what I need to draw. I'll compile at the end with my own colors.